# How to use an InternetExplorer.Application Object to open an HTMLDocument Object in VBA

Tags: vba

In Access VBA, I would like to create an HTML Document Object and open it using an InternetExplorer.Application Object without having to save the HTML document. Is there something similar to the code below that could do the trick, knowing the code leads to a `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument`.

```
Dim Explorer As Object
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = "<h1>This is a test.</h1>"
Set Explorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Explorer.navigate HTMLDoc
```

Comment: Why use the intermediate `htmlfile` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried simplifying the question. What I am looking to do is to load an HTML body template from a table, plug some values in the template using my form values and open it in InternetExplorer. I am open to suggestions if there is a simplier way to do that.

Comment: Can you not open the template in IE directly and work with it there?

Comment: @TimWilliams You mean editing the content of the HTML directly inside IE?

Comment: Yes - it should work pretty much the same as your `htmlfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate `htmlfile` object

```
Dim Explorer As Object
Set Explorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With Explorer
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "about:blank"
    .document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>This is a test.</h1>"
End With
```